# Xcode 6.4 cannot run using the selected device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I know that I repeat this topic but I didn't find the solution. I don't have developer account, I just want to run the iOS simulator with my project. All the uptdates are instaled including iOS simulatores, Compiler for C/C++/Obj-C is set as Default compiler(Apple LLVM 6.1). Also I can't choose any device on the left side of "set the active scheme", there's only iOS Device. I have tried to change the versions of XCode and iOS to earlier and nothing happened. I found

I will be very gratefull for help!

Comment: Did you import the project from another version of Xcode ? Anyway check _the deployment target_ and _iOS deployment target_

Comment: Check the Xcode prefences under the Downloads section if any of the simulators is installed

Comment: Aladin thank you very much! I had iOS Deployment Target set as iOS 8.4 when I change to iOS 8.2 it works! but… why?

Comment: Because you do not have the 8.4 simulator installed?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Xcode options select Window>Devices and see if the simulators are created. If not, you would need to create simulators depending on which one you need.